# Broadcast Receiver that checks running processes?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, process

I couldn't find any examples of such a receiver...

I want to create a broadcast receiver that checks if a defined process has been started and when it has been stopped in order to count the time the process has been running.

I'll be glad if you provide me guidance, tutorials or small examples in order to understand how to create it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no broadcasts for starting and stopping of processes, sorry.

Comment: I don't wanna start or stop them... I just wanna know when a process has been started and when has been terminated. I want to count the time between these two states.

Comment: @Seishin: "I just wanna know when a process has been started and when has been terminated" -- you indicated that you want to do this via a `BroadcastReceiver`. Presumably, you think that there are broadcasts being sent out to announce the starting and stopping of processes. You are mistaken. There are no broadcasts for the starting and stopping of processes.

Comment: Okay. Then what I can use to achieve this task? A service?

Comment: @Seishin: You could have a service constantly monitor things like `ActivityManager`. Hopefully this would not be for an app that you would ship, because the users of your app might kill you over excessive battery usage. Also, you will have to deal with the fact that users and the OS will get rid of your service from time to time. You did not bother to explain what you are trying to accomplish, but usually the sorts of things that lead developers to want to monitor processes really should be done via modifications to the Android source code itself (e.g., parental control).

Comment: The idea is simple. I want to create an app that counts the running time of particular processes (apps). So it has to register the start of the process and its end. But I really don't know how to do it so I need an advise. I think that with a service which is running on another thread will work it out.

Comment: @Seishin: I am not aware of a way to create such an app that will not be a battery hog.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the process in question, you can always edit the process so that it can now issue broadcast when the process begins and stops. Then you can use your broadcast receivers to calculate the time between the start and stop.

If you can edit the process in question, you can use persistent variables to track the time when the process has started and stopped. Or even if you cannot edit the process, you can replace all the calls to the process by a thin wrapper, which uses persistent variables to store the start-time of a process, actually call the process and finally store the stop-time when the process stopped.

If you can neither edit the process nor can edit the calls to the process, its not possible.